# Cannot delete object in python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a pyunit class defined:

```
class my_class_test(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          self._my_class = my_class()
          print self._my_class._values    
      def tearDown(self):
          del self._my_class
          self._my_class = None
```

I have three tests defined. Each add values into self._my_class._values, which is a dictionary. The problem is that each tests adds one value, and I expect these values to be reset after each test. The problem is that they persist. The output of my print statement after each test is:

```
{'foo':0, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 0}
{'foo':1, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 0}
{'foo':1, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 1}
```

Is there some way to release this memory?

Comment: What does the code for `my_class` look like?  You probably are storing the values in a class attribute and not an instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Was using a class variable instead of instance variable.